# Using Javascript to change an anchor link's text when window width changes

Tags: javascript, media-queries

I'm trying to build a simple javascript that will change the contents of an anchor link when the browser window goes below a certain width, and change it back when it goes above said width.

**HTML:**

```
<footer id="about" style="">
    <ul id="aboutFooter" style="">
        <li><a href="http://twitter.com/whatever" id="twitter">OUR 140-CHARACTER THOUGHTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="mailto:whatever@gmail.com" id="email">EMAIL US AT WHATEVER@GMAIL.COM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="middleMan">OR KEEP THINGS SIMPLE AND HIT "NEXT"</a></li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
 var mq = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 1074px)" ); 
        if (mq.matches) { 
            document.getElementById("email").firstChild.nodeValue = "EMAIL US AT whatever@gmail.com";
            document.getElementById("twitter").firstChild.nodeValue = "OUR 140-CHARACTER THOUGHTS";
        }  

        else {
            document.getElementById("email").firstChild.nodeValue = "EMAIL";
            document.getElementById("twitter").firstChild.nodeValue = "TWITTER";
        }
```

At the moment, it's not working at all - just stays on the initial values for each element. I have jQuery running on the same page, is it possible that the two are interfering?

Comment: Strange its working for me?In which case you are facing an issue?

Comment: Really? Weird. I made a live version here: http://harrisonfjord.com/folio/contactTest.html maybe it's something in the CSS that's messing with it...

Comment: in Which browser you are testing.Live version is working fine for me in FF8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a listener so it updates when the state changes. Example from http://dbaron.org/log/20110422-matchMedia (this is copy-and-paste, not my code):

```
function setup_for_width(mql) {
  if (mql.matches) {
    // The screen width is 400px or wider.  Set up or change things
    // appropriately.
  } else {
    // The screen width is less than 400px.  Set up or change things
    // appropriately.
  }
}

var width_mql = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)");
// Add a listener for when the result changes
width_mql.addListener(setup_for_width);
// And share the same code to set things up with our current state.
setup_for_width(width_mql);
```

Just change the 400px in their example to 1074px, fill in the blanks (where the comments are), and it should work for you. Like this:

```
function setup_for_width(mql) {
  if (mql.matches) {
    document.getElementById("email").firstChild.nodeValue = "EMAIL US AT whatever@gmail.com";
    document.getElementById("twitter").firstChild.nodeValue = "OUR 140-CHARACTER THOUGHTS";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("email").firstChild.nodeValue = "EMAIL";
    document.getElementById("twitter").firstChild.nodeValue = "TWITTER";
  }
}

var width_mql = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1074px)");
// Add a listener for when the result changes
width_mql.addListener(setup_for_width);
// And share the same code to set things up with our current state.
setup_for_width(width_mql);
```